# Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, batarang

I am facing the following error in my AngularJS application:

> Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ng/btstrpd?p0=document

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

After some time researching i found the solution for my problem. I have the **AngularJS Batarang** Chrome Extension installed on my browser and when it is activated i receive a javascript error. When i deactivate it, the error stops to appear.